# Two categories are loading every available product in category

Tags: magento2, product, category, product-collection

Most of my categories are working fine and only loading 12 products per page. Two of my categories are loading in every product assigned to those categories causing a very high page load time.

The categories have the same relevant settings as other categories that are working correctly (Anchor -> Yes, Display: Products Only).

Products per page on grid default value is set to 12 and products per page on grid allowed values is 6, 12, 18.

List mode is set to Grid Only.

Flat catalog category and flat catalog product are set to no.

Update:
I've traced through the codebase and found that this category is deciding to be set to isLoaded before calling _loadEntities() so it never calls the $this->getSelect()->limitPage($this->curPage, $this->_pageSize); however other categories get into this function because isLoaded is false. You can see this functionality in Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection

Comment: Hi Max Can you check in backend how many products you have assigned to this categories

Comment: @BartZalas one of them has 23 products, the other one has 2404

Comment: Any difference in layout update in categories settings? When you choice category => layout

Comment: @BartZalas nope :(

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: @BartZalas Unfortunately not I'm afraid

Comment: You can try to change this in one of your category that is showing more than 12: choice category set Display settings => display mode => products only  and design => use parent category settings   Clean cache and tell me is anything changed

Comment: @BartZalas Thanks for the suggestion but no luck :/